# Inconvenient way to reset data in 2-way-binding : Flex 4.1

Tags: apache-flex, binding, reset

We all love the inconvience of 2 ways binding. But how to easily reset the affected data in case of pressing cancel button.

I have cruised all over the internet (mostly :D ) for the answer but all the sample I saw don't have that reset button in the form o_0.

If you have any idea, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I don't use 2 way binding that much for this exact reason.  I prefer to not change the data until it's needed (which also saves on data binding if other places are using it.  I did [post something on my blog about this](http://www.michelboudreau.com/2009/12/11/keeping-model-state-in-components/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider 2 way data binding to be very convenient in many cases

If you want to reset a value to the old value; you'll you have to store a copy of that old value.  There are plenty of ways to do this.  One is to do a "Copy" of the data before your input is populated.  In the reset click handler; just copy the stored values back into the input values of your form.

Another way could be to listen for the 'focusIn' event on the component in question.  For example, if you are bidning to the text property of a TextInput, you might do something like this:

```
<s:TextInput id="textInput" focusIn="onFocusIn()"/>
```

In the onFocusIn event handler, store the old value you want to store in some public variable:

```
oldTextInputText = textInput.text;
```

In your reset handler; just swap the values:

```
 textInput.text = oldTextInputText;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But our objects graph is quite large, not simple as text. So copying them leave the dropdownlist's selectedItem not working properly...

Comment: @Pham Huy Anh I see no reason why this approach won't work w/ complex objects or a DropDownList.  But, since you haven't shared any code I can't begin to guess what issues you're having.

Comment: ... maybe it was my coding logic which made selectedItem problem... Well, if there is not "native way" to roll the data back. I think your solution is the best one, I will hang one more day before checking your answer as ACCEPTED. Thanks

Comment: Here s the reason why is doesn't work:  When you copy/backup the object, Flash player create a new instance of the object. So when the you replace/restore your original object by the backedUpOne, the dropdownlist doesn't realize the selectedItem. I am working on a workaround for it using Cairgorm3 dataCache